# Content Detail pages host Salesforce CMS content. I don't want these pages

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, salesforce-cms, digital-experience

When deploying a digital experience via Metadata API I am receiving the following error:

```
Content Detail pages host Salesforce CMS content. If you want content on the B2B_Pharma_Store1/views/newsDetail.json, add this site as a Salesforce CMS Channel.
```

I do not want content on the newsDetail page. I do not even want that page yet when I delete it from the builder and publish, it is just readded automatically.

I have tried to add a CMS Channel however am unable to add a site channel.

Comment: Can you confirm you are following the steps from [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cms_cmsworkspace-adddestination.htm&type=5) to add the site as channel and then adding the Content to the channel? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: No I didn't. In the end I think I had to change the template. I can't really remember.

Comment: @Robs did you found a solution?

Comment: Following steps listed by @Swetha fixed it for me!

Comment: N.B. @Swetha - the link in your comment is broken