# Content Detail pages host Salesforce CMS content. If you want content on the B2B_Pharma_Store1/views/newsDetail.json, add this site as salesforce CMS

Tags: lightning-experience, metadata-api, experience-cloud, digital-experience, salesforce-cms

When deploying a digital experience via Metadata API I am receiving the following error:

Content Detail pages host Salesforce CMS content. If you want content on the B2B_Pharma_Store1/views/newsDetail.json, add this site as a Salesforce CMS Channel

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This may be related to this issue:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1552 and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349403/content-detail-pages-host-salesforce-cms-content-i-dont-want-these-pages Though the solution url expired.

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on a similar post in the past [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349403/content-detail-pages-host-salesforce-cms-content-i-dont-want-these-pages) and it worked for some.

You need to add the sites as channel by following the steps in the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cms_channel_add.htm&type=5) and add the Content to the channel

> - In Lightning Experience, from the App Launcher, open the Digital Experiences app (previously named Salesforce CMS).
> - On the Digital Experiences Home tab, locate the workspace in the All CMS Workspaces table.
> - To add a channel to a CMS workspace, take these steps.
> - Open the workspace and click Channels.
> - Click Add Channel.
> - Select or create channels. To save a channel to the CMS workspace, click Add. You receive an email when your channel is available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i was able to resolve this, we have removed the newsDetail.json as looks like salesforce is adding this component by default & which is not needed, after we removed & then deployment went sucessfull without any issues